# Creating pretty url's with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

After doing a couple hours of research, I found out that there are multiple KINDS of htaccess files.

So i have a three part question

(A)What kind of htaccess file do I have?

(B)Is this the correct way of trying to  rewrite the files?

(C)Is there a way to close an htaccess file? For instance if you start a php doc, you start with `<?php` and end with `;?>` and with an html doc you start with `<html>` and end with `</html>`. How would you close an htaccess file?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.home*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.settings*)$ edit_profile.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.in*)$ pm.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.seed*)$ seed.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: htaccess files belong to the webserver - for example apache. Their purpose is to provide directory specific configuration. Imho this has little to do with programming... Nevertheless - One, Maybe - it depends on your goal, You don't "close" them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By kinds of htaccess files, do you mean files that begin with .ht? As far as I know there are .htaccess files which are used for configuration purposes, and .htpasswd files used for storing users/passwords for HTTP Digest Authentication.

You just have a .htaccess file. I don't think you need the [L] flag as that signals the end of URL rewriting for that request. Why do you have a period preceding the home, settings, seed?

Other than that everything else looks good. And to answer your last question, no you don't have to close a .htaccess file. It's not like PHP where you need to supply the ending (?>) tag.

Answer (score 1):

A) There is only one kind of .htaccess file. Apache configuration settings can either be in the central configuration (`apache2.conf` etc.), or `.htaccess` files. The advantage of the latter is that you don't have to restart the server.

B) That depends on what you want to do.

C) It's not necessary to close a .htaccess file, it's just a file containing a bunch of lines.

Comment: What I wanted to do was just rename the files. Nothing fancy

Answer (score 0):

Personally I find [this approach](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/succeed/) easier to handle - having to dive into htaccess every time you add to a site is quite dull.

I add a few file extensions to the list and don't do the existence of file checking in code but those are changes you can make according to your needs.

Comment: I doubt that method would satisfy his needs. In order for the request to be passed to index.php, you would have to point your browser to http://site/index.php/whatever. He's trying to configure URL rewriting so that, for example, when a user goes to http://site/home, it will point to http://site/index.php. Using the method described in the link you provided, you would have to point your browser to http://site/index.php/home

Comment: the rewrite makes index.php THE controller for the site. That can then use the url to direct to appropriate scripts. SO index.php would direct site.com/settings to edit_profile.php. Simply means if you add functionality to your site you only have to deal with code to manage which script is executed NOT having to jump into htaccess and write a new rule and check that its not usurped by another rule.